# SOLR FULL IMPORT ERROR, unknown character set

Tags: java, mysql, solr, dih

I am facing this error while full importing via **DIH solr 4.10.1 and tomcat8**,  also Iam using '**mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar**' connector, and my **MySql version is 5.6.20**,

My dih config is making connection with ,

```
<dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" type="JdbcDataSource"
 url="jdbc:mysql://***.***.4.96:3306/new_search_relevence" 
 connectionProperties="useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;" user="XXD" password="PPD" />
```

**PS :all my tables are utf8 encoded**

MY **ERROR** LOG in **SOLR**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown character set index for field '13109' received from server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getCharsetNameForIndex(ConnectionImpl.java:3102)
```

Comment: your field mapping is wrong, it seems you have used the field('13109') value instead of name for mysql column name.

Comment: @JunedAhsan ,Thanks.   Iam currently indexing three fields only all are named properly, could you explain what you meant ?